# Why my localhost does not work

Tags: localhost

So when I type localhost in my browser I am getting:
*Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.*

As I see in Google it should be "It Works".
My Apache is running:
nbp-229-48:pa1 PutinMac$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)

My folder: */Library/WebServer/Documents* is empty

What would I do to run localhost and be sure it works correctly?

Comment: What port are you serving on?

Comment: When you say you see it on Google and it says `"It Works"` do you mean that you use a proper domain name (not localhost) in that case?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I do not know...

Comment: @MichaelPetch I say that what I found in Google says that it should tell me It Works when Apache is running